# How to generate web service proxy https in JDeveloper

Tags: web-services, https, proxy, jdeveloper

I'm triying to create a web service proxy https in JDeveloper but when i put the wsdl (https://host/service-name/port?WSDL) i have the next issue: **No WSDL document could be found**.

I dont know how to configure JDeveloper to connect with me https web service. In this moment i have the .cer that exists in the web service but i dont know where install (in my local server or in another place).

i'm new in JD so i dont understand many features (sorry).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if your service is up and running.
2. Check if you are able to access your service through HTTP Analyzer? Go to Tools-> HTTP Analyzer-> Create New SOAP request and provide the WSDL.
3. If you are unable to access it there, you may need to change your JDeveloper proxy settings by going to Tools-> Preferences->Web Browser and Proxy-> Proxy Settings.
4. Once you are able to access the service via analyzer, you should be able to generate the web service proxy client using the wizard.
   Once your client is generated, you would need to write java code to point to the certificate's location.